# Does user care about the details while loading?

Tags: progress-bar, loading

I need to load some information on Android devices and showing a progress bar immediately came to my mind. Now here's the problem:

The time it takes to get the content ready(download/decode/buffer) is not short, but not long enough to make the user navigate away. I would say around between 8~15 seconds.

Is it good practice to also show a line of text telling the user what's going on?
Do the user care? Would it confuse the user? Does it make the user feel more  positive while the loading commences?

What I mean by a line(single line, nothing more):
[image]

See the "Checking operating system version..." above the progress bar

As a developer, seeing the details make me happy, but I'm not sure about regular users.

**TL;DR: I see this pattern used a lot with enterprise software and software installers, I'm not sure if using this pattern on a mobile app would be a good choice**

**EDIT: This is my first question on UX and it has more upvotes than my [highest voted question on stackoverflow 2.5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458258/return-value-from-async-task-in-android). Maybe I'm more suited for UX related stuff :)**

Comment: *"The time it takes to get the content ready(download/decode/buffer) is not short, but not long enough to make the user navigate away. I would say around between 8~15 seconds."* - on YOUR device.

Comment: A quote from the [Windows UX Design Principles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/dn742475.aspx): "**Don't provide unnecessary details.** Generally users don't care about the details of the operation being performed. For example, users of a setup program don't care about the specific file being copied or that system components are being registered because they have no expectations about these details. Typically, a well-labeled progress bar alone provides sufficient information, so provide additional progress information only if users can do something with it."

Comment: Sounds like a great A-B Test situation.

Comment: @and31415 It's of no great surprise to me that the *Windows* design principles can be basically summed up as 'assume the user is an idiot'.

It makes it an incredibly frustrating system to use if you're not an idiot.

Comment: @MilesRout Interesting proof point on opinion vs fact.  I find Windows easier to use than the common alternatives which I find enormously frustrating when doing some of the heavy lifting I do, especially OSX.

Comment: By the way, I'm fairly sure that *both* the description *and* the progress bar for launching InstallShield (then one you displayed a screenshot of) are pure BS, for no purpose other than to amuse the user.

Comment: @MilesRout Pointless.  Opinion based only.  Try doing a bulk file rename in OSX.  Or System -> Preferences -> Network connections in most *nix distros.  By your logic, they are all designed for stupid people.  BTW, I just a changed a file permission.  2 dialogs, 2 clicks.

Comment: @and31415: Users can always do *something* with it.  Perhaps only "Report the message that was on screen when it hung", but that's significantly better than nothing.  (If reporting it is the only thing that can be done, make that even easier by including a unique status code)

Comment: @Simon What is a 'bulk file rename'?

Comment: showing to much info could be a potential security risk?

Comment: @BenVoigt The article I linked earlier also reads: "Because the feedback provided by progress bars isn't necessarily accurate and is fleeting, progress bars aren't a good mechanism for providing information for technical support. Consequently, if the operation can fail (as with a setup program), don't provide additional progress information that is only useful to technical support. Instead, provide an alternative mechanism such as a log file to record technical support information." Don't get me wrong: I *like* details myself (as long as they're actually useful), but they do have a point.

Comment: @and31415: I think that's specific to [the information inside the progress bar](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62532/does-user-care-about-the-details-while-loading?noredirect=1#comment98389_62533), and not an accompanying label (good to have a log file as well, of course, but logging does occasionally fail too -- hiding information and trusting a user to go find it in a log file is a bad user experience, transitioning to terrible if the log file wasn't actually written due to problems with invalid path, permissions, disk full, interrupted network, or file already exclusively locked)

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but when I see the same "Loading" text on the screen for a half an hour, I imagine something along the lines of a turtle running a marathon: no efficiency. Now, when I see loading bars that have detailed text flickering across the screen so fast I can just barely read it, I think: "This program is powerful. This computer is powerful. Look at how much crap it's doing!". In reality, there probably isn't much difference in the actual speed of the program, and I know that. But the second one still feels faster, and stronger compared to the other one. My two cents...

Comment: A good exemple of fun loading messages while you patient is the loading screen of the game Sims, it keeps you interested until you know them all

Comment: I'm reminded of the loading messages that popup when loading the Sims. (Oh, I just looked up and see @NeeL had the same idea, hah!) Though those messages were made up and don't correlate to actual loading operations, they do give the impression that the program is _doing something_. What's important is that the message is short but meaningful. Users usually aren't interested in the details. But some users _may_ be interested in knowing why they must wait (even if it's <3000ms).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Showing details in a form not only developers understand is fine. If you are able to write your installation details in a more funny way than just "Checking Operating System Version" this might have two advantages:

- The user gets feedback about what's going on and **that there's something going on at all**. When installing e.g. a computer game you normally have to wait for while and for some seconds (or minutes) the progess bar doesn't move. In this situation with the single information line the user knows that his system is not frozen.
- **The user gets entertained.** If it fits your application you might want to formulate the details in a less formal way or just in a way that fits your application: "Awaking the goblins" (if this would be a game about playing with goblins)

As an alternative to the installation detail line you could also already explain some of the key functions of your app. This way the user gets more relevant information and is entertained, too. For a mobile application that installs in less than 20 seconds as you described I personally would prefer this solution.

Comment: so, "reticulating splines" is perfectly fine?

Comment: "could also already explain some of the key functions of your app." <-- like that idea very much. Installations are something very techy. Hide the technical layer as much as possible from the user. She's not interested in files being copied or expanded. Never. Period.

Comment: @JanDvorak It always depends on the audience. Sims did imho completely the right thing with "reticulating splines". The loading times of Sims are sometimes *really* long. However by bringing in such and similar phrases, they hide the actual technical layer in a matter of "yes, there is something big going on but don't care about it".

Comment: It's also handy if something *doesn't* work.  It's a bit more information when a user can report "the installer gets through 'checking hardware platform', but hangs at 'checking operating system version'", instead of "the installer hangs".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor "the installer is stuck at reticulating splines"

Comment: Hearthstone does this as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak Bear in mind that no splines were actually reticulated at any point during terrain generation.

Comment: @Bogdacutu: The user isn't going to understand the message /anyway/. If your funny phrases actually map to legitimate stages rather than being random, then they still offer useful information to the developers.

Comment: @AlexejFroehlich **I** am interested in file copy and expansion.  Always.  Period.

Comment: @anorton That might be, but you're not the user. What I wanted to say is as long as your users aren't of the type developer, administrator or something else very very tech-related, they are not interested in all those details. I'm sorry but just because you're the programmer it doesn't mean that your users will understand that files are being copied and so on. The vast majority of the users out there have absolutely no idea what is going on inside a computer. And that's OK. I have (almost) no idea about how cars work but I still drive them. I *use* them. That's the way you should see software.

Comment: @AlexejFroehlich Oh, I'm sorry--I wasn't clear: I meant I always read that information as I'm installing software *as* a user.  (E.g. Let's say I take off my programmer hat, and put on my gaming hat.  I want to know what Steam is doing as it installs Portal.) I am an information-hungry person (in general), and it drives me crazy when someone decides *for me* that I don't need certain information.  But, I realize that the current fad (at least, I hope it is a fad) is information hiding, and I'll make sure to give my users that by default, but let them be able to opt out.

Comment: @AlexejFroehlich: If someone has a flaky internet connection, the bad connection may sometimes cause installations to fail which would otherwise succeed, and successful installation may require a few attempts.  If repeated attempts fail *in exactly the same place*, however, that may be a sign that it's not just the flaky connection that's causing trouble.  The user might not know what the displayed messages mean, but may recognize that the second attempt died while showing a message somewhat similar to the first (having not observed the first attempt well enough to be sure), and ...

Comment: ...the third attempt seems to match the second (to which the user paid more attention) and the fourth attempt precisely matches the third (which was written down).  Having seemingly-legible messages will make it easier for users to notice that the first and second attempts seem to have died in the same place, but what's important is that identical operations on repeated attempts get the same message, and different operations get different messages.

Comment: @supercat so why not having the install software itself keep track of the install process and if it fails report it to the user with an error msg containing the point where it causes a problem ;-)

Comment: @anorton: Once again, *you* are an info-hungry person in general and that's ok. But most of the users out there just *are NOT*. Steam is being used by gyus who are at least some tech-savy and familiar with install, tweaking the GPU and so on. See todays phones or tablets: The installing processes for the apps in the stores do not show details at all. Just a loading bar. And there is a purpose behind it. It's not a fad. It's a valid design concept (see "visual noise", "cognitive load" etc.!) However, opting it out like you said (checkbox "show details") is a good answer to noise and overload :)

Comment: @AlexejFroehlich: Sometimes install processes don't "fail", but either hang or crash (e.g. BSOD).  An install program could keep track of the progress of an installation attempt, and report on where the previous attempt was aborted (that could be particularly helpful in the BSOD scenario) but showing text messages during the update is a simple and harmless way of adding some diagnostic ability.  For people who run the process multiple times, it can also provide a visual indication of whether something which normally flows "smoothly" is, for some reason, not (e.g. a bad WiFi connection).

Comment: I care only because it's how I know it hasn't gotten stuck.

Answer (score 34):

It can be useful for several reasons. One is that the user gets a feeling of that something is actually happening and not just a progress bar increasing. If the UI says "Checking OS Version" or "Initiating virtual processor" she gets a feeling that something good happens, even if she doesn't know the technicalities behind it.

Second, if the process would stop at a step, it would be much easier to find out what is wrong. Maybe others on the intranet had the same issue at the same step, and you may find that you need to enable unsigned code (or something else). Just make sure, messages are valid.

Comment: so, no "reticulating splines" and the like?

Comment: As an anecdotal example of your second paragraph: quite a few years ago, while attempting (and failing) to uninstall MSN Messenger, I had to *search for the percentage it failed at*. It was quite fortunate that others had mentioned the same percentage - but it would have been so much easier and more reliable if I had a name for step it failed at.

Comment: @Bob LOL! This happened white running Eclipse and trying to install on a virtual Android device. It failed and it got a name when failing :-)

Answer (score 34):

As an analogy, consider the mirrors universally installed in elevators. While these mirrors give the user a false sense of added space in the lift, they also serve as just mirrors; people tend to look at themselves and do not seem to notice how long the lift is taking to take them wherever they are going. But if they put in a countdown telling people 'xx seconds to go', they'd start complaining how slow the lifts are.

The same tactic is applied by Ubuntu, Microsoft, Apple and others. As you are installing their operating system, they talk about what you can do with your shiny new computer when the installation is over. Minor details about the installation itself? Users simply don't care about those, at least the majority of them.

Comment: I was confused reading the first words... Mirrors and elevators as analogy for install... wtf?? But after reading it completely I really like this example, kudos @humbleware :-)

Comment: +1 the best examples of this I've seen take advantage of the opportunity to show people things that are possible with the app that they otherwise wouldn't have realised. Many video games do something similar, offering tips and "Did you know?"s

Comment: I still remember the incredibly optimistic blurbs Microsoft put in the Windows 95 installation screens: "What you want to do, and more, is now possible" and "Whatever you do will be more fun". Sign me up!

Comment: @DanC You can do anything at Zombocom! Anything at all. The only limit is yourself.

Comment: A very long time ago a Linux installer started installing in the background while asking the needed questions.  If the user were done before the installer was finished, the installer let the user play Tetris.

Answer (score 14):

showing what the program is doing while working on a progress bar gives an additional indication of progress. There is also a nice way of doing this involving a details screen:
[image]

This method doesn't just show the progress of the installation as a whole, it also shows what the current step is, what the previous steps is and sometimes even the progress of the current step.

Many installers using this method don't show the details screen from the start, but have a separate button you can click to display it, so people that aren't interested don't have to see it.

An additional benefit of this method is that, if your installer has any options that require more than a few lines (like a list of localizations or optional packages), you can make your installer big enough to show those options properly without having a bunch of ugly empty space beneath the progress bar, like your example has.

Comment: Oh no Vista! It burns :p.

Comment: Personally, I do hate all the details. I changed my own NSIS setups to remove the details and even the summary and also the "Nullsoft..." in the lower right. And I made the ESC key a direct way to exit the installer, without the boring confirmation "Are you sure".

Comment: One aspect of this is that errors and warnings may now be visible to the user. So you also need to communicate to the user exactly what their responsibilities are towards those messages, and how they are supposed to handle them.

Answer (score 9):

**No**, they don't care about the details. But the great thing about it is that they know exactly what is happening, it feels like he/she has control.

Comment: I don't think this has to do with control. Even the opposite can be the case if a user gets overwhelmed by foreign language.

Answer (score 8):

I would argue that "8~15 seconds" could in fact be long enough for an impatient user to navigate away or to think the app may have crashed. Changing messages is therefore useful as an indicator that something is happening and conveys a little more "why" of waiting than a buffering circle or similar.

Whether the messages are of importance to the actual activity, are tips/features of some kind or a "reticulating splines", I think depends on the user base. For an average player of SimCity, reticulating splines was good UX because who cares what's actually happening in the background so long as it's loading. But here you say "download/decode/buffer" so I think what's happening is important. Is it taking a long time on the download for example; do I have a dodgy connection?. This is potentially useful information to the user.

Comment: +1 for mentionin slow connection. I have slow connection, and I like to know if something is loading (even if those are few kylobytes If I can see some progress is better then nothing)

Answer (score 3):

With an installation of 8-15 seconds, the user should not get the impression that the progress bar ever gets stuck (be sure to monitor the progress fine-grained enough so that processes that take more than one second or sometimes a not completely predictable amount of time - such as searching and downloading some extra files - consist of enough sub-steps to guarantee this). Fine-tune the percentage of progress that the individual steps are counted as  in such a way that on typical systems/in typical situations the growth of the bar is continuous.

Apart from that, if you give the user two or three sentences to read that may not be important for him, but that keep them busy reading for 8-15 seconds, they will not really notice the time it takes to install. A surprising animation instead of text might even be better in this respect (as long as it does not lead to longer download/install times).

On the other hand, people may be *used* to a handful of installation interfaces (screenshots of InstallShield and NullSoft are shown in other answers), especially in the PC world such that any deviation from the general structure might confuse them (is the installation complete? Or is this alrady the program starting? Or will there still be questions left to answer and configure?)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how long you expect the load time to be. If you expect it will be ~10 seconds or less, most users probably will not care about details. If you expect it could be several minutes/hours, users might want more details than just a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Really I think Marvin did a pretty good job of answering this question already.  Something I'm going to add though is that, at least in some cases, Civilization games' installers tend to show exactly which file is being installed, right down to the individual pngs. They'll include the path as part of the name of the file, and since they'll basically go directory by directory, you'll see them slowly work their ways up and down the directory trees, but almost instantaneously go from file to file.

This is very informative and encouraging to the user that anything is happening, and that it's not just frozen.  It also makes them feel like actual progress is being made, more so than if you just show them a progress bar and some vague text by themselves. Some users like this feel - the feel of watching progress happen continuously - which is part of the reason you have a progress bar in the first place.

It might come across as something tailored more to developers, but it really isn't at all. Normal computer users know good and well what a file is and should be able to tell what's going on.